# In Ark Survival Evolved, do you lose gained experience points when you die?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

In Ark, do you lose all/any of your experience points when you die? I haven't bothered looking when I die and I'm to scared to try now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

The only thing you'd lose is all of your equipment/inventory, assuming you can't just go back and find it within the 15 minutes that your bag will be there.

Even on hardcore you don't technically lose your exp, you just lose the whole character haha.